# Why Google Console Delayed acceptance myapplications

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I placed my application and it was not accepted yet. It took 15 days. I downloaded an update for the application to be accepted quickly, but it is still under review. Today is the third day after the update. What is the problem and what should I do to quickly accept the application?

I have no idea what to do.